# Converting frozen hash brown patties from oven cooking to stove top

Tags: potatoes

I have some store brand frozen hash brown patties that only show to cook them in the oven.  They have to cook at 450 degrees for 15 - 20 minutes, and it is 80 degrees outside.  Can they be cooked in a frying pan on the stove top without ruining them?

Comment: Consider thawing the patties before hand, then try @Escoce's method. Some brands may work, others not so well, so experiment with one. Move a hash brown from the freezer to the refrigerator the night before.

Comment: Or just nuke them for a minute before putting in frying pan.

Answer (score 2):

Microwave is on the blink so had to improvise.

Added a whole bunch of grapeseed oil to the bottom of a frying pan and put it on medium-high heat. Wasn't quite "deep fat fry" level of oil. But, it was a small lake in a 10" fry pan covering the whole bottom.

Once the oil swashes around like water, and is obviously hot, place the frozen hash browns in gently. The oil will start to crackle immediately because of the ice in the patties.

Cook for four minutes on the first side, then flip to the second side, and cook for another four.

Check if you've reached the desired crispiness. If not, flip again and cook for a couple minutes; and then repeat on the second side. It should definitely be up to tater top crispiness by now! Either that, or your oil wasn't hot enough.

Place on a layer of paper towel, and then pat the top with another paper towel to remove excess grease, as there will be some.

I also cooked a sweet Italian sausage patty with the hash browns, and they both turned out well using the above method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, but it will add some additional fat to your hash browns.

Pour a tablespoon or two of peanut oil (or veg oil if you prefer) into your frying pan and heat it up.

Lay your hash browns down into the pan, and check the bottom for desired doneness, anywhere from 2-5 minutes depending on the hash brown and the amount of heat you are using. Then flip the over and check for doneness again.

The reason it takes less time this way is because they are being cooked in oil rather than being exposed to hot air. It takes longer for the heat to get to the center of the hash browns in the oven.

However, why don't you just make fresh hash browns. You just shred a potato or few, perhaps some onion as well and just drop the pile into an oiled hot pan heated to low or medium low heat, and flip it once the bottom just starts to burn, again then check when this side is ready.

Comment: You should probably thaw the hashbrowns before pan frying like this.

Answer (score 0):

How I do it.
1). Spray pan lightly with olive oil.
2). Put frozen Hash Brown Patty in Skillet.
3). On my electric burner set it to 6. Cover the pan
4). Flip the patty every 4 minutes.
Next).
I set the HB patty on a plate and cover with Lid.
It sits while I throw a precooked sausage patty in the hot skillet.
It defrosts in about 90 seconds- flip once. Breakfast is served.